# Поиск слова или нескольких слов в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, reactjs

Собственно стоит цель подсветить совпадения слов с соблюдением определенных условий в строке.

примерно такие могут быть строки:

1. `Awesome test`
2. `Test string`
3. `Stringtest (test test)`
4. `Stringtest Test/Test`
5. `Stringtest Test/Stringtest long test`

Искать нужно то что введено в `input`, например слово `test`.

Есть несколько условий поиска:

1. Начинать поиск в только вначале каждого слова. то есть если ищем слово `test` `Stringtest` не подходит по совпадению.
2. Слова могут быть разделены пробелом, `/`, и могут находится в скобках (test test)

немогу понять как правильно записать все условия для поиска. Тому что в `input` можно ввести `(` и `)` и регулярка ломается

**вот рабочий** [пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-alex-j8h0n?file=/src/App.js)

реализацию я понимаю так:

в [компоненте](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-alex-j8h0n?file=/src/Search.js) заменяем все вхождения слова с помощью регулярки.

Comment: Искать слово целиком `\\b${inputText}\\b`  Если нужно матчить только начало, то без `\\b` в конце.

Comment: @GrAnd хм.. а как заматчить начало слова? например у меня есть `test` а юзер вводит только `tes` ?

Comment: `\b` как раз и является токеном границы слова, т.е. начала или окончания (нюанс: с кириллицей не работает).

Comment: @yar85 Кириллица не нужна. Она не будет использоваться.

Comment: Ну так попробуй предложенное решение через `new RegExp(\`\\b${inputValue}\\b\`, 'gi')` :) и если оно поможет - хорошо бы код самоответом добавить.

Comment: @GrAnd 
спасибо за помощь. я немого доработал регулярку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного допилил регулярку учитывая комментарии по вопросом.
Теперь она ищет по словах начиная сначала слова.

Вспомогательная функция

```
function escapeRegExp(text) {  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');}
```

финальный вариант который заработал для меня:

`` const pattern = `\\b${escapeRegExp(inputText)}`; ``

так как в `input` можна ввести скобки, из за которых сломается поиск в строке. Потому я их экранирую, а уже потом использую.